# not getting email for custom field woocommerce

Tags: email, woocommerce

I am using `woocommerce` (free plugin).. I am trying to add one custom field to the billing fields..

here it is:

```
// ADDED HOW YOU GOT TO KNOW ABOUT OUR SERVICE FIELD
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'About_Our_Service' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function About_Our_Service( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_meat'] = array(
    'label'       => __('How you Got to Know About Our Service?', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder' => _x('', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => false,
    'clear'       => false,
    'type'        => 'select',
    'options'     => array(        
        'google-ads' => __('Google', 'woocommerce' ),
        'google-search' => __('Yahoo', 'woocommerce' ),
        'warrior-forum' => __('Bing', 'woocommerce' ),
        'facebook' => __('Facebook', 'woocommerce' ),
        'other' => __('Other', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    );

     return $fields;
}
```

The problem is: I am not getting the value in my mail for the custom field which was added to the billing fields..  Anyone who already used `woocommerce` can help me on this... ?

I already created some more custom fields which was added to the checkout (BUT these're not added along with the core fields), for these fields i'm able to get values in my mail..

By the ay, i checked this [thread](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-hooks-and-filters/): but didn't much info related to mail..

please kindly someone look into this..

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, custom billing/shipping fields are saved as post meta for the order post. So in general, you can retrieve them with the typical WordPress `get_post_meta()` function.

But in WooCommerce 2.2, you don't need to as you can pass the field name directly to an array of fields that WC will show as a list in the email:

```
// pre-WooCommerce 2.3
function kia_email_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys['Some field'] = '_some_field';
    return $keys;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'kia_email_order_meta_keys');
```

This method has been deprecated in version 2.3, probably so translation can be better. As of 2.3 you will need to target a different filter and send slightly different data.

```
// WooCommerce 2.3+
function kia_email_order_meta_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    $fields['some_field'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Some field', 'my-plugin-textdomain' ),
                'value' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_some_field', true );
            );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'kia_email_order_meta_keys', 10, 3 );
```

I wrote a tutorial on [Customizing WooCommerce Checkout Fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/517/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer, in the codex is specifically meant for this purpose:

http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/add-a-custom-field-in-an-order-to-the-emails

I haven't implemented this myself but it's probably your best shot.